# uuid and rosdep on OSX 10.9.2

Tags: rosdep, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to install ROS Hydro through Homebrew on my laptop with mac os x 10.9.2. The process of solving the dependencies seems to be not easy, and I not able to complete this phase due to this error:

```
$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro groovy -y

WARNING: Metapackage "diagnostics" must buildtool_depend on catkin.
Error: No available formula for uuid 
Error: No available formula for tango-icon-theme 
executing command [brew install uuid]
Error: No available formula for uuid 
Searching taps...
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  homebrew: command [brew install uuid] failed
```

What is uuid? Can someone help me please?

Thanks in advance,
Andrea

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/140006/uuid-and-rosdep-on-osx-10.9.2/) by [-Andrew-](https://answers.ros.org/users/9051/-andrew-/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you following the instructions on the wiki [1]? The two formulae are in the ros/hydro tap, so execute `brew tap ros/hydro` (which is part of the install instructions) and then try the rosdep command again.

Also I just noticed that you are using the option `--rosdistro groovy`. If you want to install hydro, choose `hydro` instead of `groovy` here...

Moreover, depending on which variant you are installing, you might need some or all of the fixes described here, in case you are not aware of that yet [2].

You should be able to install the `desktop-full` variant of hydro on OS X 10.9.

- [1] http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source
- [2] http://answers.ros.org/question/94771/building-ros-on-osx-109-solution/?answer=101176#post-id-101176

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0